# Four people are rolling a die once. What is the probability of $2$ people getting the same number?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am doing as following-

$1^{st}$ people get a number from any $6$ number in $6$ ways, $2^{nd}$ people get a different number from rest of $5$ in $5$ ways, $3^{rd}$ people get another different number from rest of the $4$ in $4$ ways, and last people get a number from any of $1^{st}$, $2^{nd}$ or $3^{rd}$ people in $3$ ways.

So, total favourable outcome = $6\times 5\times 4\times 3 = 360$

Total outcome = $6\times 6\times 6\times 6= 1296$

So, probability = $\frac{360}{1296}$.

Is it a right way doing this. I don't even know the answer is right or wrong. I don't find this in books or over internet.

Comment: What if second person gets the same number ?

Comment: Perfectly sound method.  You have computed the probability that no two people get the same number, so the answer to the title question is $1-\frac {360}{1296}$.

Comment: Side note:  I assume the title question means "at least two", so that outcomes like $\{1,1,2,3\},\;\{1,1,1,2\},\;\{1,1,2,2\}$ would all count as successes.  If you meant "exactly two" (so the last two of my examples would not count) then the answer is different.

Comment: You have counted the "unfavourables." But to get the favourables is now easy.

Comment: "*I don't find this in books or over internet*" This problem is essentially a rewording of the famous [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) using six possibilities instead of the usual 365 possibilities.  It has been discussed under that name many times in many forms of media.

Answer (score 4):

You have correctly computed the chance that no two people get the same number.  The chance that there is at least one match is the complement of this, so $$1-\frac {360}{1296}=\frac {936}{1296}$$

If you want the chance of exactly one match, so the unordered rolls are aabc, you have $4 \choose 2$ ways to pick the people who match, $6$ ways to pick the matching number, $5$ ways to pick the first non-match, and $4$ ways to pick the second non-match giving a chance of $$\frac {6 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{6^4}=\frac {720}{1296}$$

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be the following, since the question is what is the probability that exactly two people get the same number, not two or more (if the question is two or more, then the result is 1 - the probability that none of the persons get the same number).
You can tag the persons to follow the solution easier as **A,B,C** and **D**. Now without the loss of generality you can say that **A** and **B** will get the same number, since you tagged them arbitrary. And now you can calculate:
It doesn't matter what person A gets.
There is then 1/6 probability that B throws the same number as A.
C and D both have a 5/6 probability of not throwing the same number as A and B.
So the probability of exactly two persons getting the same number is:
1/6 * 5/6 * 5/6 = 0.11574074074 or about 11.57%.

Another way of calculating this (which might be more explanatory) is calculate that exactly two persons get number 1. Well A has 1/6 probability to get a 1 and so does B, C and D both have 5/6 probability of throwing not 1, so total probability of exactly two persons throwing 1 would be 1/6 * 1/6 * 5/6 * 5/6. But since we can do this for every number on the dice we multiply the above equation by 6 and get 1/6 * 5/6 * 5/6 as above.

Edit:
As Ross Millikan pointed out, there is another subset of solutions that has to be addressed, namely do you accept the throws where A and B get the same number but also C and D get the same number (e.g. a throw 1122). The solution above (11.57%) takes the throw 1122 as valid. However if you want to avoid those throws then the probability for D's throw is 4/6 , since he can't roll the same number as A and B but also not the same number as C. So that solution would be:
1/6 * 5/6 * 4/6 = 0.09259 or about 9.26%.

Comment: This is not correct as you can't arbitrarily assume that A and B are the two that got the match.  Then when you say "B and C" have a 5/6 probability... you mean "C and D". When you consider D, you need to avoid C's throw as well, or you will accept throws like 1122.

Comment: I would disagree you can absolutely determine that A and B will be the ones that get the match since the labeling is completely arbitrary and the order is not important. I did edit the mistake, thanks for that. The point about 1122 being accepted is true, but I did consider that to be in the realm of solution as still only two people get the same number (technically you get two times two people).

Comment: You still didn't apply the $4/6$ for D instead of $5/6$. Where are the rest of the 1296 rolls if not four distinct (360 rolls as OP says) and your 120 rolls?  The other patterns (two pair, three of a kind, four of a kind) are much less likely.