# probability that 2 people getting the same number

Tags: probability

> 1. $4$ people are rolling a die once. what is the probability that 2 people getting the same number?
> 2. Two cards are drawn at random without replacement from a well shuffled deck of $52$ cards. Find the probability that the cards are
>      both red  or both king?

Solution:

1. Total outcome= $6*6*6*6$

   2 people can get same number in $6*1*5*4$ ways. However, they can get same number in ${4\choose 3}$ ways. So, favorable outcome= 120*6. Hence, probability= ${5\over 9}$
2. prob of both red= ${26\over 52}*{25\over 51}$
   prob of both king= ${4\over 52}*{3\over 51}$
   prob of both red-king= ${2\over 52}*{1\over 51}$
   So, prob of both red or both king= ${26*25 - 4*3 - 2*1\over 52*51}$

Are the solutions correct?

Comment: It's "probability of both red, _plus_ probability of both king, minus probability of both red king". You have a minus to much there.

Comment: for the first one, do you mean "exactly two"  or "at least 2"?  That is, if all four roll $6's$, is that a success or a failure?

Comment: About 1st one. Check this -  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859451/four-people-are-rolling-a-die-once-what-is-the-probability-of-2-people-gettin. Exactly your problem.

Comment: Why post the same problem multiple times?  If you don't understand an answer someone gave, comment on their response.

Comment: It's just exam pressure, I even forgot that I solved this one earlier, and even forgot to search!  Apologies :)